# How to send xml data using http post in angularjs and receive html

Tags: angularjs, xml, post

```
$scope.PostCall = function(data,d) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $http({
                        url :"https://localhost:9443/root/p/testPost2",
                        method : "POST",
                        withCredentials: true,
                        cors:false,
                        headers: {
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Content-Type'
                                },
                     data: data,
                    }).success(
                            function(data) {
                                    $scope.alertModal("yha...");

                            }).error(
                            function(data,status, headers, config) {
                                $scope.alertModal("Error!"+status);
                                $scope.status = status;
                            });
                };
```

method postcall is made for a http post call to a other origin server with xml data. but error :Response for preflight is invalid (redirect).